# When Running Airflow Migrations job the airflow doesnt seem to have access to logs folder

Tags: permissions, airflow, azure-aks, airflow-2.x

airflow version - 2.8.1

Running in a controlled AKS- where you are only allowed read only system

```
airflow@airflow-create-user-7zv66:/opt/airflow$ ls
airflow.cfg  config  dags  logs
airflow@airflow-create-user-7zv66:/opt/airflow$ cd logs
airflow@airflow-create-user-7zv66:/opt/airflow/logs$ ls
airflow@airflow-create-user-7zv66:/opt/airflow/logs$ airflow
Unable to load the config, contains a configuration error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/pathlib.py", line 1116, in mkdir
os.mkdir(self, mode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/airflow/logs/scheduler/2024-02-10'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/config.py", line 573, in configure
handler = self.configure_handler(handlers[name])
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/config.py", line 757, in configure_handler
result = factory(**kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/log/file_processor_handler.py", line 50, in __init__
Path(self._get_log_directory()).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/pathlib.py", line 1120, in mkdir
self.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/pathlib.py", line 1116, in mkdir
os.mkdir(self, mode)
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/opt/airflow/logs/scheduler'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow", line 5, in <module>
from airflow.__main__ import main
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 68, in <module>
settings.initialize()
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 546, in initialize
LOGGING_CLASS_PATH = configure_logging()
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/logging_config.py", line 74, in configure_logging
raise e
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/logging_config.py", line 69, in configure_logging
dictConfig(logging_config)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/config.py", line 823, in dictConfig
dictConfigClass(config).configure()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/config.py", line 580, in configure
raise ValueError('Unable to configure handler '
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'processor'
```

I have enabled persistent volume and set it to company accepted storage class why is it still unable to create the scheduler folder?

Is there a way around this?

Comment: https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/22992